# How to use multiple middlewares in Next.js using the middleware.ts file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-frontend, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js project and trying to implement multiple middleware in my application. While I've found examples of using a single middleware in Next.js using the **`next-connect`** package, I prefer to achieve this without relying on any external packages.

I have a **`middleware.ts`** file where I would like to define and use multiple middlewares. Here's the code snippet from my **`middleware.ts`** file:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

  const userId = request.cookies.get('userId')

  if (!userId) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', request.nextUrl.origin).href);
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
    matcher:'/profile/:path*',
};
```

Her's what i tried:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";

export function profileMiddleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const userId = request.cookies.get("userId");

  if (!userId) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("/auth/login", request.nextUrl.origin).href
    );
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export function authMiddleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const userId = request.cookies.get("userId");

  if (userId) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("/", request.nextUrl.origin).href
    );
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export default {
  middleware: [
    {
      matcher: '/profile/:path*',
      handler: profileMiddleware,
    },
    {
      matcher: '/auth/:path*',
      handler: authMiddleware,
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: According to this article: [How to Chain Multiple Middleware Functions in NextJS](https://reacthustle.com/blog/how-to-chain-multiple-middleware-functions-in-nextjs), you need to write your own middleware that will stack the other middleware, there is no builtin feature to combine middlewares.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide

Comment: Hey, I have two middlewares and two configs, how to combine them?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603369/how-to-use-multiple-middlewares-in-next-js-using-the-middleware-ts-file/77230182#77230182) out:

Answer (score 25):

You can use middleware chaining for this purpose. Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Create a folder called `middlewares` in your `src` folder.
2. Create a file called `stackHandler.ts` in the `middlewares` folder and paste this content into it:

```js
import {
  NextMiddleware,
  NextResponse
} from "next/server";

export function stackMiddlewares(functions: MiddlewareFactory[] = [], index = 0): NextMiddleware {
  const current = functions[index];
  if (current) {
    const next = stackMiddlewares(functions, index + 1);
    return current(next);
  }
  return () => NextResponse.next();
}
```

3. Create another file called `withUser.ts` and paste this content into it:

```js
import {
  NextFetchEvent,
  NextRequest,
  NextResponse
} from "next/server";

function getSearchParam(param: string, url: any) {
  return url.searchParams.get(param);
}

export const withUser: MiddlewareFactory = (next) => {
  return async(request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
    const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

    if (["/profile"]?.some((path) => pathname.startsWith(path))) {
      const userId = request.cookies.get("userId");
      if (!userId) {
        const url = new URL(`/auth/login`, request.url);
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
      }
    }
    return next(request, _next);
  };
};
```

4. Finally in your `middleware.ts` file in the `src` folder paste this content:

```js
import {
  stackMiddlewares
} from "@/middlewares/stackHandler";
import {
  withUser
} from "@/middlewares/withUser";

const middlewares = [withUser];
export default stackMiddlewares(middlewares);
```

### Note

Define the MiddlewareFactory type as below (ignore this if not using Typescript):

```js
import {
  NextMiddleware
} from "next/server";

export type MiddlewareFactory = (middleware: NextMiddleware) => NextMiddleware;
```

### Note

You can create as many middlewares like `withUser` as you want by creating them and then importing them into `middlewares.ts` and pushing them in the `middlewares` array.

Comment: this approach does not support defining `export const config = {...}` to handle URL matcher, do you have any idea how to incorporate that into it?

Comment: @crollywood the `["/profile"].some((path) => pathname.startsWith(path))` is a custom matcher which you will need to have in each middleware functions if you need to run the middleware function for route/path subset.
The declarative next.js middleware config/matcher would limit all the middlewares which probably is undesired for people which look for multiple middlewares.
Its funny that express had good middleware 10years ago and next only supports one. Maybe its because it would be harder for the to specify execution order?

Comment: Does a solution exist for combining two middlewares via OR operation?

Comment: There's no way Next.js doesn't support this out of the box

Comment: This approach also does not allow a middleware to short circuit the chain when middleware produces a response body

Comment: Does this answer support multiple middlewares modifying the response object, setting cookies, etc?

Answer (score -2):

From the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/nested-middleware):

> Declare your Middleware in the root folder and use `NextRequest` parsed URL to define which path the Middleware should be executed for.

I would therefore suggest preferring this approach over the one described in the most upvoted answer.

Comment: I think you should add some examples as the docs itself doesn't provide any (at the time of this comment)