# How to combine multiple libraries middleware in Nextjs 14?

Tags: next.js, middleware, supabase, next-intl

I have a problem with 2 libraries that I want to implement in the NextJS app: [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs) (pkt 4) & the [next-intl](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router#middleware). Both of them share middleware methods that return right-away the `NextResponse`. I was trying to utilize both of them but failed all the time returning both at one `NextResponse`.

I was trying custom middleware with `stackMiddlewares` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603369/how-to-use-multiple-middlewares-in-next-js-using-the-middleware-ts-file), but both of them are not returning `NextResponse`, only `NextMiddleware`.

I have two middlewares

```js
export const withI18n: MiddlewareFactory = (next) => {
  return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
    
    // WHAT TO DO WITH THAT?
    const response = createMiddleware({
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      locales: SUPPORTED_LOCALES,
      pathnames,
      localePrefix,
    });

    return next(request, _next);
  };
};
```

the [client docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client?environment=middleware) that outputs the `updateSession` method.

```js
export const withSupabaseSessionUpdate: MiddlewareFactory = (next) => {
  return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {

    // WHAT TO DO WITH THAT
    const response = await updateSession(request);

    return next(request, _next);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my question resolved with `next-intl` [discussion panel](https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/discussions/422#discussioncomment-8664562). I just followed the `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs?language=ts), and that's it!